# Resizing contents in a ScrolledComposite

Tags: java, swt, grid-layout

```java
ScrolledComposite scrollFormItemComposite = new ScrolledComposite(c, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);

GridData formItemCompositeGridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
formItemCompositeGridData.horizontalSpan = 4;
scrollFormItemComposite.setLayoutData(formItemCompositeGridData);
GridLayout formItemLayout = new GridLayout(1, true);
formItemLayout.marginHeight = 0;
formItemLayout.marginWidth = 0;
formItemLayout.verticalSpacing = 0;
formItemLayout.horizontalSpacing = 0;
scrollFormItemComposite.setLayout(formItemLayout);

Composite formItemComposite = new Composite(scrollFormItemComposite, SWT.RESIZE);
formItemComposite.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL|SWT.HORIZONTAL));
FormProvider formProvider = new FormProvider();

formProvider.createForms(formItemComposite);
scrollFormItemComposite.setContent(formItemComposite);
scrollFormItemComposite.setExpandHorizontal(true);
scrollFormItemComposite.setExpandVertical(true);
scrollFormItemComposite.setMinSize(formItemComposite.computeSize(300,SWT.DEFAULT));
```

The previous lines of code give me the following output. I want the contents to shrink as the form becomes smaller. I dont want the horizontal scroll bar to appear. How do I prevent the text box from being hidden?

[image]

Comment: So why are you using `ScrolledComposite` if you don't want scrolling?

Comment: I want the vertical scroll because the form items are lengthy.. But when i resize or make the window small,, the content should shrink and the horizontal scroll shouldnt appear. Note - there is a button next to the text box which is hidden after resizing.

Comment: @greg-449 can i enable scroll on the composite without using the scrolledcomposite? I want vertical scroll no matter what.

Comment: Here is an article that describes how to layout such a form in a ScrolledComposite : http://www.codeaffine.com/2016/03/01/swt-scrolledcomposite/ HTH

Comment: You really need to provide a proper [mcve] so we can test things, the current code uses a `FormProvider` class.